# Special characters from forms using as variables on the same page

Tags: php, html

I've ran into an issue with special characters being used as variables.

Heres my HTML that has something to do with characters:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
...
<form class="nav-search left" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input name="summoner_name" type="text" placeholder="Summoner Name" required autofocus />
</form>
```

Heres the PHP which is trying to get the `$_POST`:

```
$summoner = htmlspecialchars($_POST['summoner_name']);
$summoner_name = strtolower($summoner);

-> outputs nothing, as it isn't read properly.
```

Letters such as `Śý` will be used, and I think these are from extended-latin

Comment: What does a simple `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: I believe this question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886954/how-to-post-special-reserved-characters-from-html-forms-to-php-pages?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Using [this walkthrough](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) as a jumping off point, I would say:

## First

...verify that your application is emitting the `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` header. There's really no reason not to, and it's really simple.

## Next

...the first place you may have a real issue is your form. Again referencing the above link [the encoding to be used for application/x-www-form-urlencoded data is practically undefined](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Make sure your form is using the attribute `accept-charset` set to `"utf-8"` (`accept-charset="utf-8"`).

## One More

...If you aren't using a database in here, then there's nothing to do there, but if you ever store this data in a database, that's almost *definitely* where the mis-encoding is happening.

There's a lot that could go wrong in the database - from connecting, to how the data is stored, to how the data is retrieved. If you are using a database at all to store this data before it is sent back to the browser, take extra care to make sure the database is properly encoding and retrieving UTF-8 text.

## Finally

...`strtolower` [doesn't convert characters not represented by your locale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php). If your locale is, say, `en-US`, your special `UTF-8` characters will not be converted, and you'll get an empty string (if there aren't any other characters).

If you were to use [`mb_strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php), you could pass an encoding like: `mb_strtolower($summoner, 'UTF-8');`
This properly handles special characters.

Comment: so i've done `<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>` & `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` & `<form method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">` but it still doesn't seem to work, and yes - my website isn't using a database at the moment.

Comment: Check out my edit. You're using a function that (most likely) will drop any special characters.